# Struggling to read birth record of my German Jewish great-grandfather

Tags: germany, birth-records, 1870s, rhineland-palatinate

I found this birth record for my ancestor Max Mayer who was born in Speyer, Germany in 1879.

I'm struggling on two counts:

- I can't read his father's full name, I'm pretty sure it ends Marx Mayer, but what are the two words before
- What do the two stamps mean on the bottom left? My family is Jewish and fled Germany around the time of WW2

[image: birth cert]

Comment: Hi, Matt -- welcome to G&FH.SE!  Is this the only record you can access from this record set, or can you look at others that might have the same stamps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The father's given name is Marx Mayer. At the first appearance of this name he is further identified by the words "der Kaufmann" (merchant or business man). At the bottom of the document his name appears again. The line before that reads "Read, accepted and signed". The handwritten word is "unterschrieben", indicating that the words in the second line represent his signature.
2. The first stamp, dated 4.1.1939, states, that as a Jew, Maximilian Mayer was required to carry the additional first name "Israel". (Women were required to adopt the name "Sara".) The second stamp of 1946 rescinds the provisions of the first one.